# is it worth to learn google data store

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-datastore

i want to use google app hosting , but i have read that they don't give option of mysql or sql.

Now i am building the java website using mysql.

Is data store same as sql. and will work with hibernate

Should i learn it or not

Comment: You should learn it just because it's the only persistence option available with Google App Engine. Next, you will decide if your application can be ported from mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datastore is not a "drop in" replacement for SQL.  I have worked with the python version of GAE a bit, so the java version might be slightly different...

- You want to limit the number of queries you run in a page and the number of objects you query.  Doing otherwise will lead to looooong load times.  Also inserting lots of data (200+ objects) probably wont work.
- You can't do range scans on more than one column in a table (for instance 1 < x < 2 and 3 < y < 4).  Also a lot of query types are not supported compared to a full fledged database engine.
- You should edit and insert data via your program.  The datastore admin allows you to insert some data after the initial object is created but some types (text,blob) are not editable.
- Any changes to your models will require you to loop through all instances and make changes (especially if you delete an attribute on your model).  You can ignore it but chances are you will want to reclaim the space used.
- Backing up data and uploading data to your application is a bit more complicated.  The remote api makes things easier but compared to some of the tools for other engines it seems primitive.

Comment: then why would anyone use data store , just because google hosting

Comment: It is relatively cheap (something like .5c per gb/day or .15c per gb/month over the initial amount) and scales well as more load is put on your website.  The downside of that availability is limited query types and query latency as data can be fetched from multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Data Store [is not the same as SQL](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Differences_From_SQL).

Extracted from [somewhere](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?pli=1):

> You cannot currently use Hibernate
>   directly. The differences between the
>   App Engine datastore and SQL were too
>   great to get the standard Hibernate up
>   and running under App Engine. App
>   Engine does support JDO and JPA, so
>   you may be able to convert your
>   Hibernate code to use one of these ORM
>   interfaces.

If you want to host your apps in Google App Engine you should, unless you want to pay for Goolge App Engine for Business, that does provide SQL.